# CFFILE creating a file with APPEND or WRITE

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I'm having an issue with a coldfusion11 website, under certain conditions my attempt to create and send a report file is failing, apparently due to permission issues. I can't recreate the issue on in my test/dev environment so I need to understand what is happening for a live fix, I can't just start arbitrarily changing code on production. The current code creates the file using an APPEND action like this:

```
<cfset f_dir = EXCEL_PATH >
<cfset f_name = CreateUUID() & ".csv">
<cffile action="APPEND" file="#f_dir##f_name#" output="My Report "
addnewline="Yes">
<cffile action="APPEND" file="#f_dir##f_name#"
output="Title,#attributes.title#" addnewline="Yes">
```

Elsewhere in the code are similar functions that use WRITE as the first cffile action, like this:

```
<cfset f_dir = EXCEL_PATH >
<cfset f_name = CreateUUID() & ".csv">
<cffile action="WRITE" file="#f_dir##f_name#" output="My Report "
addnewline="Yes">
<cffile action="APPEND" file="#f_dir##f_name#"
output="Title,#attributes.title#" addnewline="Yes">
```

The code that uses WRITE first is not failing, this leads to my question:
Is there a difference between creating a file with action="APPEND" and action="WRITE" in coldfusion 11?

Comment: What are you looking at that makes you suspect permissions?

Comment: I'm getting a 403 error from the webserver instead of a document.

Answer (score 2):

Ron - Write is "create" - it makes a new file. Append is used to add data to an existing file on the disk. They are different actions.

Try modifying your code as follows:

```
<cflock name="#f_name#">
<cfif NOT fileexists(f_dir & f_name)>
  ... do your WRITE action>
</cfif>
</cflock>

<cflock name="#f_name#">
.... do your APPEND action  - you can be sure your file exists at this point.
</cflock>
```

Note, I usually use a named lock to serialize these two actions. Sometimes your code trips over file handles not quite released. Not typical but if your disk is ever thrashing it can happen.

Comment: Thanks Mark, it appears append will also create a file if it does not exist. My question was, is there a difference between append and write when they are used as the first command that creates the file? That is, would the two files have different permissions. Or are you suggesting a timing issue may result from creating a new file with append?

Comment: I did not know that about append. I've always used "write" to create and append to add to a file (so good to know - thanks!). But yes, I'm suggesting that creating files and writing to them takes some care - and locking effectively serializes these two events. These are two different systems - the OS file system and the JVM. So there can be issues with releasing file handles. It's better to avoid it.